# Negative value in shape parameter of gev.fit

Tags: r

I got negative value for shape parameter by using `gev.fit` in `ismev` package of R. What does it indicate? Does it mean that it belongs to another distribution instead of generalized extreme value (GEV) distribution?

here is the output of `gev.fit`:

```
$conv [1] 0

$nllh [1] 12.96933

$mle [1] 13.796261 1.847000 -1.084086

$se [1] 0.001307101 NaN NaN
```

The value of shape parameter=-1.084086, it is too negative which doesn't approximate zero.

Answer (score 2):

"positive values of the shape parameter imply a heavy tail, and negative values imply a bounded upper tail" (package ismev, pp.10)